# Probability using normal random variable

Tags: probability, statistics

I need to solve this but I'm not sure how since I need to use normal random variable and I'm not familiar with that :

Robin is shooting ducks and he never miss. Probability that duck will show is $\frac19$. If Robin shoots 1000 times using aproximation of normal random distribution find probability that Robin hits duck more than 800 times?

Comment: In which contexts did you already use normal random variables or did you see them appear?

Comment: I think it's about a series of independent bernuli attempts, each attempt, the probability that Robin shoots is 1/2, and that duck will show is 1/9, which means that the success probability for bernuli attempt is 1/18. Use the formula to determine what is the probability for success more than 800 times

Comment: @user1067083 Where does the 1/2 come from? I don't see it in the question.

Comment: It's just a thought...but the fact that Robin shoots using normal random distribution means that the probability he'll shoot in a certain momemnt is 1/2

Comment: Why? You are inventing parameters!

Comment: Again...it was just a though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X \equiv$ number of duck hits. Then $X \sim \text{Binomial}(1000, 1/9)$. We are asked to find $P(X > 800)$. Since $n=1000$ is sufficiently large and $p=1/9$ isn't too extreme, a general rule of thumb is that we may use a normal approximation. Let $Y \sim \text{Normal}(np, np(1-p))$. That is, let $Y \sim \text{Normal}(1000/9, 8000/81)$. Then by applying a continuity correction, we standardize to $Z \sim \text{Normal}(0,1)$ as follows:
$$
P(X > 800) \approx P(Y \geq 800.5) = P\left( Z \geq \dfrac{800.5 - \frac{1000}{9}}{\sqrt{\frac{8000}{81}}} \right)
$$
Hopefully you can finish it off from there.